# Error in C program when using a C file in #Include directive (Multiple definition error)

Tags: c, linker-errors

Scenario :

A C application created in Netbeans IDE with below two files:

*some_function.c*

```
#include <stdio.h>
int function_1(int a, int b){
    printf("Entered Value is = %d & %d\n",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

newmain.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //function_2(); //Error //function name not allowed
    function_1();
    function_1(1);
    function_1(1,2);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

When learning the need of the header file in a C program, I tried the above application (as it is).  It got compiled and gave the output as below

> Entered Value is = 4200800 & 102
>   Entered Value is = 1 & 102
>   Entered Value is = 1 & 2

**Question 1 :** (I realize, in starting stage, to understand the process of the linker program is tough, hence i ask this question.) Is my assumption correct, that when linking, "the linker will check for the function name and not the arguments" in a condition the header file not used?

Regarding the header file usage, I came across this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/608631/should-every-c-or-c-file-have-an-associated-header-file/608712#608712) and there it said as, we can include the C file itself using the **#include**. So, I used the below line in the file **newmain.c**

```
#include "some_function.c"
```

As expected it shown the below error

> error: too few arguments to function 'function_1()'
>   error: too few arguments to function 'function_1(1)'

And also, I got the below (unexpected) error:

> some_function.c:8: multiple definition of `function_1'
>   some_function.c:8: first defined here

**Question 2:** What error I did when including the 'c' file itself, as it gives the above said (unexpected) error?

Comment: The only thing you need to understand is that `#include` directive is replaced by preprocessor with actual file content. So it doesn't matter which file you include -- it's content will be put in place of that `#include` directive. Only after such a substitution actual compilation process will be started. And compiler doesn't process header files, it only processes `.c` files, turning them into `.o` (object) files, and then linking object files to the actual binary (resulting file).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are probably using a pre-C99 dialect of C, which has "implicit function declarations". This means that functions without declarations are taken to have this kind of signature:

```
int function_1();
```

i.e. returning an `int` and accepting any number of arguments of any type. When you pass an argument list that is incompatible with your function definition, you invoke *undefined behaviour* at runtime.

Concerning the multiple definition errors, think of it. Each translation unit you include `some_function.c` will have its own definition of the function. It is as if you had written that definition in every other `.c` file. C doesn't allow multiple definitions in a program/library.

Answer (score 1):

I (the questioner) post this answer for a quick understanding for some C programming starters. This answer **inspired from the answers by [@juanchopanza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31759700/error-in-c-program-when-not-using-header-file/31759779#31759779) &  @Sam Protsenko** which are in this post.

**Question 1 :**[Implicit function declarations in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9182763/implicit-function-declarations-in-c/9182835#9182835)

**Question 2:**
When using the below line

```
#include "some_function.c"
```

The result application will change like below after the preprocessor activity
some_function.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int function_1(int a, int b){
    printf("Entered Value is = %d & %d\n",a,b);
    return 0;
}
```

newmain.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*"#include "some_function.c"" replace begin by preprocessor*/
    #include <stdio.h>
    int function_1(int a, int b){
        printf("Entered Value is = %d & %d\n",a,b);
        return 0;
    }
/*"#include "some_function.c"" replace end by preprocessor*/

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    //function_2(); //Error //function name not allowed
    //function_1(); //Error
    //function_1(1); //Error
    function_1(1,2);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

**Note : In the above two file, the function function_1 is there in two places**
So now the below error is meaningful

> some_function.c:8: multiple definition of `function_1'
>   some_function.c:8: first defined here